# SSH fails in one EC2 instance but works in another

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I am trying to ssh into an EC2 instance (1.1.1.1) from another EC2 instance (2.2.2.2) and yet another EC2 instance (3.3.3.3).

In the instance 2.2.2.2, I can successfully connect to 1.1.1.1

```
~$  ssh ubuntu@1.1.1.1 -i mykey.pem
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0664 for 'mykey.pem' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
```

However, in instance 3.3.3.3, the connection fails with a time out.

```
~$ ssh ubuntu@1.1.1.1 -i mykey.pem
ssh: connect to host 1.1.1.1 port 22: Connection timed out
```

The 2.2.2.2 and 3.3.3.3 instances are both Ubuntu 18.04.4. They have the exact same inbound and outbound rules.

Why does the ssh connection fail in 3.3.3.3?

###############################################################

Edits(2021-02-18):

The instance `1.1.1.1` and instance `3.3.3.3` are in the same VPC.

SSH connection from `1.1.1.1` to `3.3.3.3` had a timeout.

SSH connection from `3.3.3.3` to `1.1.1.1` had a timeout.

SSH connection from either `1.1.1.1`/`3.3.3.3` to `2.2.2.2` works and vice versa.

I have tried to launch a new instance `4.4.4.4` in the same VPC as `2.2.2.2`. The connection between them works.

So, there must be some problems with the VPC of `1.1.1.1` and `3.3.3.3`.

Below are the security rules of the network of that VPC:

[Inbound Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MqeB.png)

[Outbound Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDE42.png)

Comment: What are security groups between the instances? Are they in same VPC? Are they publicly available? You need to provide networking details of your setup.

Comment: @Marcin Instance 1 and Instance 3 are in the same VPC while Instance 2 is in another VPC. All three of them are publicly available.

Comment: What about details of security groups? Is instance `1.1.1.1` available from other instances? Does it only fail from `3.3.3.3`?

Comment: @Marcin Yes. `1.1.1.1` is available from other instances. It is even available from my home computer (windows). It only fails from `3.3.3.3`. `1.1.1.1` has an inbound rule of port `22`; protocol `TCP`; source `0.0.0.0/0`. Both `2.2.2.2` and `3.3.3.3` have an outbound rule for all ports; source `0.0.0.0/0`.

Comment: @Marcin I made some edits to the post.

Comment: You wrote that only 2.2.2.2 and 3.3.3.3 have outbound rules. What about 1.1.1.1?

Comment: @Marcin It has the same outbound rule as 2.2.2.2 and 3.3.3.3. (Port: All, Protocal: All, Destination: 0.0.0.0/0)